# Why are the y axis frames to my roguelike not working?

Tags: python

I am coding a roguelike, and am drawing each individual frame if the "coordinates" of the map are a certain number. Note: the indentation is correct in my project, it's just that stackoverflow is confusing. I made this code:

```
x = 0
y = 0
name = ""
i = 0


def lv1():
global y
global x
while i == 0:
    print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n")
    if x == 0 and y == 0:
        print("@ - - - - - - - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - []")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        move = input("")
        if move == "d":
            x += 1
        elif move == "s":
            y += 1

    elif x == 1 and y == 0:
        print("- - @ - - - - - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - []")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        move = input("")
        if move == "a":
            x -= 1
        elif move == "d":
            x += 1
        elif move == "s":
            y += 1

    elif x == 2 and y == 0:
        print("- - - - @ - - - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - []")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        move = input("")
        if move == "a":
            x -= 1
        elif move == "d":
            x += 1
        elif move == "s":
            y += 1

    elif x == 3 and y == 0:
        print("- - - - - - @ - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - []")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        move = input("")
        if move == "a":
            x -= 1
        elif move == "d":
            x += 1
        elif move == "s":
            y += 1

    elif x == 4 and y == 0:
        print("- - - - - - - - @ - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - []")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        move = input("")
        if move == "a":
            x -= 1
        elif move == "d":
            x += 1
        elif move == "s":
            y += 1

    elif x == 5 and y == 0:
        print("- - - - - - - - - - @")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - []")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        move = input("")
        if move == "a":
            x -= 1
        elif move == "s":
            y += 1

    elif x == 0 and y == 1:
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        print("@ - - - - - - - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - []")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        move = input("")
        if move == "d":
            x += 1
        elif move == "s":
            y += 1
        elif move == "w":
            y = 0

    elif x == 0 and y == 2:
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - []")
        print("@ - - - - - - - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        move = input("")
        if move == "d":
            x += 1
        elif move == "s":
            y += 1
        elif move == "w":
            x -= 1

    elif y == 3 and x == 0:
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - []")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
        print("@ - - - - - - - - - -")
        move = input("")
        if move == "d":
            x += 1
        elif move == "w":
            y -= 1


lv1()
```

But for some reason, when I got down to y axis 2 and try to go back to y axis 1, It infinitely prints \n. Does anyone know what the problem

Comment: What exactly is inside your `while`, only the print or all the code below it?

Comment: we cannot know what is the _correct_ indentation in your project, you need to edit the code to let us know how it actually looks like. You can use three backticks ```  to surround the code to create a code block.

Comment: there are no indentation errors, and the while is to serve as a loop so it prints the frames repeatedly.

Comment: The way your code is posted at the moment does give an indentation error because currently there's nothing inside your `while`.

Comment: You have to [edit] your code anyway to include a [mcve] rather than all that code which can't even be taken and run. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I need help to figure this problem out

Comment: your `move=="w"` in `y==2` is doing `x-=1` not `y-=1` making `x=-1` which your code have nothing to do with and so just printing `"\n"`

Comment: Thanks! It was just a silly error... It's fixed now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a glitch -- the code is doing exactly what you told it to do.

x and y both start at 0.  If the user enters "s", y is increased to 1.

Your if/else block does not have any case that matches x == 0 and y == 1, so the `print('\n\n\n\n\n\n\n...')` line runs forever.

Yes, I know the code has these lines:

```
elif x == 0:
    if y == 1:
```

But those lines won't ever be checked, because of the way the code is structured.  `if x == 0` is the very first condition and it is true, so the `elif`s are never checked.

Comment: Wow! That's very helpful! But is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: Do I have to switch the elif x == 0 to elif y == 1?

Comment: I fixed it!!!! All I had to do was use the and operator for everything! Yes!! Thank you so much for your help. without you I would never have known!

Comment: wait.
Now it infinitely prints \n when I go up to y level 1.